# 'Field Not Found' and 'Required Field' Error Importing CSV to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, csv, import

I just tried importing a .CSV file to a Data Extension (there are only 3 rows as I'm doing a test), but I keep getting an error. My CSV files have the right headers that can be mapped, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
ValidationErrors:

  Field Not Found: 1
  Required Field: 2
```

This is what is shown in the accompanying text file (anonymised):

```
Row Number  Error Number  Error Code  Error Details  Row Data
0  24032293090  FieldNotFound  Email   
0  24032293091  RequiredField  email  [redacted Casesafe ID][Ms.][Jane][Doe][jane.doe@redacted.com]
1  24032293092  RequiredField  email  [redacted Casesafe ID][Ms.][Jane][Smith][jane.Smith@redacted.com]
```

Does anyone know what the FieldNotFound and RequiredField errors are and how I can fix my CSV file to successfully import the contacts? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the correct delimiter in the import (e.g. comma vs semicolon)?

Comment: I've checked that the delimiter is a comma and not a semicolon - is that the right delimiter?

Comment: also would check on using text qualified if possible as your issue could be a comma in one of your fields is being read as a delimiter and not as part of the text field - which can blow up your file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with a delimiter in the Data Extract that you set up OR what delimiter Import Activity is expecting, so check those 2 places.

Usually, it would be enough to use a pipe or tab delimiter to properly split the values, however, if you have a really extensive file, you can use a more "powerful" delimiter as "☺" for example (in other words, the character that is not present in the file).

Regarding the errors:

1. `Field Not Found: 1` - The first one says that it cannot find the Email field.
2. `Required Field: 2` - Some of your non-nullable fields in the receiving Data Extension do not get the value from those 2 rows. Again, a proper delimiter should solve it.

Here is an [official article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320718&type=1) about Import File Activity errors (yet not all of them).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I imported a .CSV file and checked that the delimiters were all commas in the file, and on importing I also selected comma as the delimiter. I will give pipe and tab delimiters a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case, and the problem was a field name with **space behind**
like this:  "field name "